# Why is my custom workflow not being shown in the associated list (SharePoint 2013)?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am a bit new to SharePoint Designer and am having some trouble with custom workflows. I am tasked with migrating some SharePoint 2010 lists to a new SharePoint 2013 site. Due to complex workflows, these are being done manually.

I have created the list in the 2013 site and created a 2010 workflow for the list by clicking on "New..." in the Workflow section of SPD 2013. I rebuilt the new workflow to match the old one. However, the workflow is not showing up under Workflows:

[image]

In the actual workflow though, it says that the associated list is correct:

[image]

Perhaps a separate issue, but I noticed this issue while trying to add the ManualDispo_Req column (old 2010 list shown below):

[image]

What is this column and how do I add it? It currently doesn't show up as an option in the Modify View, but I assume this is because the workflow isn't associated yet.

Any information would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to publish the workflow. When you will open workflow in sharepoint designer, you will find the publish option in Ribbon in workflow settings

[image]

Comment: So simple! Thanks. The tutorials I was looking at left that part out...

Comment: Now what if I made these flows using ms edge? They aren't even in this registry for me...

Comment: I'm working on SharePoint 2013 workflow, even after publishing the workflow it is not visible/associated with the list.